# Is there a playable postgame?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Can you continue to play the game after beating it, completing any missions you haven't done yet, or does the game lock you in if you've saved at the end, forcing you to play through again to get back at any missed content?

If there is a postgame, is there anything inaccessible or otherwise significantly different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The game reaches a fairly definite conclusion before the credits roll, so if you choose to continue playing you'll be sent back before the point of no return identified by you

> attacking the Cerberus headquarters and mounting a full-scale assault on the Reapers

This is basically kicking you back to an auto-save, as any experience you gained during the final few fights seems to be reverted. Since you're brought back before beginning the above-mentioned missions, you're free to play them over to explore the different endings.

Comment: So basically the answer is 'No', and it's just like Mass Effect 1 except that it's kind enough to keep an autosave at a reasonable location for you?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah. Although if you're just interested in exploring the various endings, it may be more convenient to save in the interim that comes between the two events to save you the trouble of having to do the entire end-game over again, since it's relatively lengthy.

Comment: Assuming you don't start any other missions after finishing the game, there is a "restart mission" auto save that places you very close to the end of the game, if you want to see the various endings.

Answer (score 0):

You're sent back to before the attack on the cerberus headquarters.

Comment: Can you clarify more specifically?  Is everything still accessible?  Does it save anything that may have happened between that point and the end of the game, or is it literally just kicking you back to an autosave before that event?  Can you repeatedly replay the end of the game (and possibly pick up different endings)?

Answer (score -2):

You can't do side missions or anything after you start the second Tuchanka mission.

Comment: This answer is wrong, there's whole sections of the game that continue after Tuchanka...