# Point of no return?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any important points of no return?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53542/are-there-any-important-points-of-no-return)

Like in Mass Effect 1, if you wanted to continue after you finished the game, you had to keep a save from before Illium.

Is there a similar point in ME3? And if yes, where? (As spoiler free as possible please)

Comment: I know the excitement of getting a new game and wanting to ask lots of questions, and I've made a few errors on this front myself, but when you're using the exact same language as the questions you're duplicating, it's a pretty clear indication that you just haven't even bothered with the search button. Try it. It's handy. You can even prepend your search with `[mass-effect-3]` to limit the results appropriately.

Comment: Well seems I missed that question. I'll close it.